# Finding the SQL column that is different in using EXCEPT

Tags: algorithm, t-sql

using EXCEPT between selects finds the records that are different. 
Given a Key to lookup records, how can I specify which COLUMNS caused the difference?
Thinking of a binary search of some kind on the columns of the table to reduce individual EXCEPTS by column, looking for a better way.

Sample:

```
select 'A','B','C','D','E'
except 
select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
```

result: B, E

```
select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
except 
select 'A','B','C','D','E'
```

result: F, Z

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL + DML, and desired results.

Comment: if you are using except it will return the whole row rather than the individual column: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-except-and-intersect-operators-in-sql-server/

Comment: Exactly. I am looking for a way to find the columns that triggered the difference in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this would be possible or even desirable.

In you example you are comparing to rows, but EXCEPT i one of the set based operations i SQL. They work on two different sets or relations, performing the comparable opartions you would see in mathematics comparing sets.

so

```
Table A Except Table B
```

returns all the members of Table that are not in Table B.

Lets expand on your example:

```
select 'A','B','C','D','E'
except 
(select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
union
select 'A','F','X','D','Z'
)
```

Except returns the members in the first set, that are not present in the second set, that comes out as the sole member of the first set.

But what would you want as output? Since, by definition, the result of the Expect is not a member of the second set, if yoy want a column by column comparison, this would have to be against all members of the second set, or in this case

```
'B','E'
'B','C','Z'
```

You see, now we are not doing a set operation any more.

Another problem is that a Table has columns, that are distinct. Your suggested output does not take this into account.

Would you like to see this output?

```
select 'A' C1,'B' C2,'C' C3,'D' C4,'E' C5
except 
select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
....
 C1  C2   C3   C4   C5
NULL 'B' NULL NULL 'E'
```

or This output

```
select 'A' C1,'B' C2,'C' C3,'D' C4,'E' C5
except 
select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
....
Column1
'C2,C5'
```

or This output

```
select 'A' C1,'B' C2,'C' C3,'D' C4,'E' C5
except 
select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
....
Column1 Column2
'B'       'E'
```

or This output

```
select 'A' C1,'B' C2,'C' C3,'D' C4,'E' C5
except 
select 'A','F','C','D','Z'
....
Column1
'B,E'
```

To return to set based operations, they work on sets, or tables that are similar in structure, and they return a set that is similar in structure.

Only one of my suggestes outputs does that, and you still have the problem of what you want to return.

IF you can specify why you need to find these differences we could make a suggestion as to how to make it happen

This is the full comparison of each line in each set to the others, returning the columns that differ:

```
select distinct
     case when a.c1!=b.C1 then a.C1 else null end C1
    ,case when a.c2!=b.C2 then a.C2 else null end C2
    ,case when a.c3!=b.C3 then a.C3 else null end C3
    ,case when a.c4!=b.C4 then a.C4 else null end C4
    ,case when a.c5!=b.C5 then a.C5 else null end C5
from (values 
    ('A','B','C','D','E')
    ,('A','B','C','D','Z')
    ,('1','2','3','4','5')
    ) a(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
cross join 
(values 
    ('A','F','C','D','Z')
    ,('A','F','C','D','Z')
    ,('A','F','C','D','Z')
    ,('A','B','C','D','E')
) b(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
where 
    not (
    a.C1=b.c1 
    AND a.C2=b.c2 
    AND a.C3=b.c3 
    AND a.C4=b.c4 
    AND a.C5=b.c5)
```

The thing is, you cannot do what you want to do, simply by using set based operators. If you can further define your needs perhaps we can find a solution.

(Please note, that it is not a complete solution above, I do not check for nulls, and the performance is terrible, basically a cartesian product